# how to use round function with query have where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to query something from mysql database and put condition that check equality between a value in the table but after round it and other value also after round it how to do this 
in php codeigniter ,plz help
 i put this instruction put it didn't work

```
$t=round($latitude,4);
$t1=round($longitude,4);    
$this->db->select('place_name');
$this->db->from('place');
$this->db->where(round(`Latitude`,4), $t);
$this->db->where(round(`Longitude`,4),$t1);
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the round call, because right now you're trying to execute a PHP `round()` function, not the SQL one:

```
$this->db->where('round(`Latitude`,4)', $t);
                 ^--                 ^--
```

quoting it turns the whole thing into a string, which gets passed into the DB.

Comment: the error gone but it maybe after rounding become zero, the Latitude in my database is double and i want to round it,in this case it maybe convert it to string and gave 0 ,can you understand what i want????

Comment: mysql `round` returns the same type as what you pass in. round a double, you get a double back. round an int, you get an int. but note that passing in a PHP `4.321` as your $t/$t1 is *STILL* going to be a float, you should probably force a string, e.g. `sprintf('0.4f', $t1)`